# ¿Cómo hacer una ruta dinámica en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

Tengo estos valores en el app.Config en mi proyecto:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="RutaEvidencias" 
         value="D://Users/WA5699CR/OneDrive - GrupoMonge/Desktop/Evidencias/"/>   
</appSettings>
```

Y necesito hacer la ruta dinámica porque el proyecto se ejecutará en distintas máquinas. Esta ruta se utiliza para guardar pantallasos de pruebas con Selenium.

Ya intenté con el `|DataDirectory|`

Comment: Hola Walter, tu proyecto es Web o WinForm ??

Comment: si estas usando un proyecto web puedes usar una ruta de tu servidor, si estas usando un proyecto winform puedes usar una ruta de una carpeta compartida, deberías especificar mas tu pregunta